# simple way to configure or modify indentation in default blueprints for `ember generate`

Tags: ember-cli

I am calling `ember g controller foo` command to output predefined snippets for controllers.
The project I am working in needs tab based indentation but `ember-cli` blueprints use space indentation by default.

Is there a simple way to configure `ember-cli` to use tabs instead of spaces?
The [ember-cli docs](http://www.ember-cli.com/#generators-and-blueprints) explain how to override blueprints, but taking this approach becomes quite cumbersome for every generator in a project.
It also appears that an overriding index file in `blueprints/controller/index.js` exposes an `afterInstall` callback passed an options argument. It seems I can grab some relevant information about the file names passed to this options object and manually reformat the files, but I'd prefer to take a simpler approach.

Comment: Your editor probably has the ability to tabify multiple files. Or you could write a one-line search and replace command.

Comment: This is a good idea; if there isn't a way to configure it I might take this route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ember-cli developers intend to make `ember generate` commands respect configuration settings specified by an [.editorconfig](http://editorconfig.org/) file:

https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3664

Once someone implements a solution in the above issue, specifying indentation preferences in an `.editorconfig` will solve this problem.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I put indent_size = 4 but still generates with 2 spaces. Not that I have a solution, just saying.

Comment: thanks for testing @brownie3003, updated the answer.